# Ubuntu 19.10 screen glitches

Tags: graphics, 19.10

I recently installed ubuntu 19.10 on my new laptop(Asus x571GT with nvidia 1650 GTX as graphic card) and I've noticed that the screen starts to glitch whenever I'm using ubuntu (the problem doesn't seem to happen when I'm using windows) and it's starting to bother me because it happens so frequently

I thought it might be an issue with the GPU so I tried to change the primary GPU to the Intel's built-in GPU but it doesn't seem to have any effect on my conditions

Does anyone have any idea what should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is driver independent, then you could try the next options:

- Use different desktop manager: `lightdm` instead of `gdm3`
- Use different desktop environment: `xubuntu-desktop`, `budgie-desktop`, `mate-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop`, `kubuntu-desktop`
- Use older kernel
- Try other cable

Comment: thank you for your quick response 
but unfortunately for me none of the above suggestions worked for me
i wonder do you know the source of the problem so i may search for a solution my self?

Comment: It's could be hardware specific configuration. You could also try different ubuntu versions or even other distributive to check. Also, make a video to show how it looks like. Maybe someone have encountered it earlier and could advise. Try 16.04, 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NVidia or Nouveau driver?  I had a lot of odd issues like that when using Nouveau drivers.  Ubuntu 19.10 comes with NVidia v435 drivers, so hopefully that is installed.  Easiest way to check is run Software Updates and check Additional Drivers tab.

Comment: hi
i am using Nvida-driver-v435 as you mentioned but since it didn't change anything i switched to Intel's built-in GPU
but again nothing has changed and i still get the same glitches